# Shell script to check automorphic number is not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

```
echo "Enter A Number: "
read num
show=`expr $num`
flag=1
square=`expr $num \* $num`
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
        flag1=`expr $num % 10`
        flag2=`expr $square % 10`
        if [ $flag1 -ne $flag2 ]
        then
                flag=0
                break
        fi
        num=`expr $num / 10`
        square=`expr $num / 10`
done

if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
then
        echo $show "is NOT An Automorphic Number"
else
        echo $show "is An Automorphic Number"
fi
```

This is a code to check automorphic number. Basically those numbers are present at the end of its square number. Like 25 stays at the end of 625.

It is only working for input 5. It's not working for 25, 76 etc. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because I am not a fan of `bash` for arithmetic I write sample `awk` program which do the check:

```
{len=length($1);
pow=$1 * $1; 
div= 10^len; 
if ($1 == pow % div) print $1 " is An Automorphic Number"; 
else print $1  " is not An Automorphic Number"}
```

It just take care about the length of input number and set accordingly the things. Here is my test:

```
[ ~]$ echo 1 |awk '{len=length($1);pow=$1 * $1; div= 10^len; if ($1 == pow % div) print $1 " is An Automorphic Number"; else print $1  " is not An Automorphic Number"}'
1 is An Automorphic Number
[ ~]$ echo 5 |awk '{len=length($1);pow=$1 * $1; div= 10^len; if ($1 == pow % div) print $1 " is An Automorphic Number"; else print $1  " is not An Automorphic Number"}'
5 is An Automorphic Number
[ ~]$ echo 76 |awk '{len=length($1);pow=$1 * $1; div= 10^len; if ($1 == pow % div) print $1 " is An Automorphic Number"; else print $1  " is not An Automorphic Number"}'
76 is An Automorphic Number
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

You might as well only print the numbers that **are** automorphic:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 11 5 25 625 76 111 12890625>infile

$ awk '{s=$0^2; r=$0"$"};s~r'  infile

5
25
625
76
12890625
```

Or, in a more cryptic form:

```
$ awk '$0^2 ~ $0"$"' infile
```

Or, if you want an explicit answer for each number:

```
$ awk '{out=" NOT "} $0^2 ~ $0"$" {out=" "} {printf "%20s %s%s",$0,"is"out"An Automorphic Number",ORS}' infile
                  11 is NOT An Automorphic Number
                   5 is An Automorphic Number
                  25 is An Automorphic Number
                 625 is An Automorphic Number
                  76 is An Automorphic Number
                 111 is NOT An Automorphic Number
            12890625 is An Automorphic Number
```

#### Previous solutions.

You might just check that the trailing portion of the square match the `n` number.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=${1:-625}
square=$((n * n))
[[ $square =~ $n$ ]] && itis="" || itis="NOT"
echo "$n is $itis An Automorphic Number"
```

#### About your script

There are several issues with your script.

- In general you should use an arithmetic expansion instead of the very old `expr`.
- It is easier to define the input number as an argument of the script.
- The change of `square` should be also `square`: square=$((square/10)). Not the `square=$((num/10))` that you had.

Making some changes, your script would become:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=${1:-625}

flag=1
square=$((n * n))
num=$n
echo "Testing =$num= and square =$square="
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
        flag1=$(($num % 10))
        flag2=$(($square % 10))
    echo "Testing +$num+ with +$square+ that generate =$flag1= and =$flag2="
        if [ $flag1 -ne $flag2 ]
        then
                flag=0
                break
        fi
        num=$((num / 10))
        square=$((square / 10))
done

if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "$n is NOT An Automorphic Number"
else
        echo "$n is An Automorphic Number"
fi
```

And you will call it like:

```
$ ./script 625
625 is An Automorphic Number

$ ./script 76
76 is An Automorphic Number

$ ./script 111
111 is NOT An Automorphic Number
```